# JQuery: Ajax POST call doesn't send data

Tags: php, jquery

Firebug says that request was sent to server with 200OK but PHP array $_POST is empty.

```
var pass_data = {
    'email':$("#email").val(),
    'verifyemail':$("#verifyemail").val(),
    'password':$("#password").val(),
    'confirm_password':$("#vPassword").val(),
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'localhost/pages/register',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: pass_data,

});
```

Request headers:

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  86
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host    localhost
Referer http://localhost/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you trying to access the data in PHP?

Comment: **If GET request works but POST doesn't** it's most usually the issue with redirect. That said, while the request initially accessed the first URL and got redirected to another URL then all the POST data were not forwarded along to another URL. Therefore all the data gets lost. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37217199/996010

Comment: Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally avoid using jQuery return values directly in variable declarations. The quoting can make parsing inconsistent. Suggest this:

```
var pass_data = $('form').serialize();
```

Let jQuery do the heavy lifting.

P.S. Just noticed your variable declaration for pass_data had a trailing comma after the last element. That's malformed. Same issue with the object you're passing to $.ajax. Get rid of the trailing comma on the last pair.

Answer (score 1):

```
var pass_data = {
    'email':$("#email").val(),
    'verifyemail':$("#verifyemail").val(),
    'password':$("#password").val(),
    'confirm_password':$("#vPassword").val()
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'localhost/pages/register.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {posted_data: pass_data}
});
```

You should be looking at **$_POST['posted_data']** on `register.php`.

Comment: Also, please eliminate the extraneous commas and add the semi-colon as displayed in my code above.

Comment: Can you post the contents of register.php?

Answer (score -1):

```
id   = $('#id').val();
etc  = $('#etc').val();

data = {
  id: id,
  etc: etc
}

const formData = new FormData();
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    formData.append(key, value);
});
```

so basically you have to get the value from the input you want to send to the backend ( with jQuery or querySelector() ) and make that an object so you can append the data to the formData() object

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P my bad, I rarely post answers here. I edited it