# ajax post not sending data

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, serialization

UPDATE: I Figured it out. Was a URL issue, which redirected and cleared the POST before it was sent to the server.

```
$('#addbtn').on('click',function() {

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/create/",
  dataType: "json",
  data: $('#MultiAdd').serializeArray(),
  success: function (data) {
    // this returns Failed. Please Try Again. c_name=
    // c_name should equal the value from post. 
    alert(data.msg)
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {}
 });

});
```

I can not seem to get this to post the data. Ive tried so many variations. Looking at this for hours trying to see whats wrong.

I have tried `data: {test:'test'}` (did not work)

the GET function does, but I need this to be POST. 
I have also tried normal .serialize(). Still didnt work.

This does work to show me the values. but ajax will not POST them in the submission.

```
console.log($('#MultiAdd').serializeArray());
```

(on the page, the form and ajax codes are dynamically added, but I dont think that would change much, Ive tested that already.)

Update: (i'm using codeigniter) - Server-side. Trying to access the [input name="c_name"]

```
public function create()
{
   $value = $this->input->post('c_name');

   $msg = array("msg"=>"Failed. Please Try Again. c_name=".$value); 

   die(json_encode($msg)); 
 }
```

Comment: have you tried the full url?

Comment: Yes the url works, I have sent the GET test, and values were sent. Its POST I can't seem to have the values sent

Comment: can you show us your server-side code?

Comment: How do you know the data isn't being sent?

Comment: Could you clarify what's going wrong? Is it sending the POST to the server, but not sending the data? What is it sending instead?

Comment: added the server side- I'm using codeigniter.

Comment: my bad.. I thought about something else...

Comment: when I place alert(data.msg) inside success, it returns everything except the actual "c_name" value from the post

Comment: @Idealcastle Have you used your browser tools or Fiddler to look at the actual request that is being sent?

Comment: What web browser are you using. There is an immensely useful Developer Tool called the `Network` tab. Let me know if you need instruction

Comment: wow. yeah I'm an idiot. @JasonP /create/ = 301 moved and redirected to /create (without backslash). Thanks for that quick tip. what a waste of 2 hours trying to work with the game

Answer (score 7):

**If GET request works but POST doesn't** it's most usually the issue with redirect. That said, while the request initially accessed the first URL and got redirected to another URL then all the POST data were not forwarded along to another URL. Therefore all the data gets lost.

Some common cases that might occur (depending on server configuration):

- **"/method/"** might get redirected by your site to **"/somethingCompletelyElse/"**
- **"/method"** might get redirected by your site to **"/en/method"** (language redirect)
- **"method/"** might get redirected by your site to **"method"**
- **"method"** might get redirected by your site to **"method/"** (common, extra backslash)
- **"example.com/method"** might get redirected by your site to **"www.example.com/method"**

You get the idea. If you look in **network panel** and notice that there is no data sent but response was 200 OK then it's good idea to check if **Request URL** in network panel is the one that you specified in your code. Although this will be possible only in modern browsers. In older browsers you won't even know that URL has been redirected.

For Example (see that "en/" is missing in my request url):
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `contentType` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/create/",
  dataType: "json",
  data: $('#MultiAdd').serializeArray(),
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  success: function (data) { //success },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //some sort of error }
 });
```